# WebDriverIO Not Picking Up Elements

Tags: node.js, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I'm trying to do a fun side project to get into learning how to properly test my website with WDIO.

I've already accomplish this on a few sites I use everyday, but I write all my websites in Angular, and because it creates a single page application I decided to test on Twitch, which is also a single page application.

Pretty much I just went around, trying out seeing if I could login with my credentials and what not. I only just ran into an issue when Twitch injects something into the web page, and for some reason webdriver doesn't seem to pick it up.

Pretty much what I did was try to watch an ad, what that does is create a simple ad pop up. However I can't seem to grab anything from the iframe the ad is in. Here's a few examples I tried.

```
browser.waitForExist(".bits-ad-provider--truex");
browser.click(".bits-ad-provider--truex");

browser.waitForExist("span=I'm Done");
browser.click("span=I'm Done");
```

I even want as far to do this:

```
var el = $('iframe');
console.log(el.length); // Returned 0;
```

All this code was sent after the ad popped up, and it just sites their and waits forever. I'm unsure what to do at this point because it's getting extremely frustrating issue I've been fighting nearly all day.

Here is a snippet of the html of the site I for some reason cannot grab. I would like to click on the **hd-container-header-action** span class however for some reason it isn't being picked up just like the other ones using this code:

```
browser.click('.hd-container-header-action');
```

If you'd like to watch an ad to see the components just head over to any twitch channel, and click the twitch bit icon.

So for example:

https://twitch.tv/sodapoppin and click here:
https://gyazo.com/5a0a0e41177d56d86de0c6d769de68cf

Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: If it is angular then you should be using `protractor` and not `webdriver.io`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Twitch (the site I am grabbing these components from) isn't in Angular. I am just trying to practice the concept of using web driver with a single web page application.

Comment: Can you post a full js and package.json i can try?